# How do I find a cheap car stereo with aux?

Tags: ford, audio

I have an 20 000 km car that will break down soon, don't want to invest in it.

The antenna is broken and I just want to listen to some sweet tunes and pods from my phone, but the car doesn't have a aux-connection. I'm trying to find a really cheap radio that just does that. I have been looking at the iSimple IS31, it's an antenna adapter and the best opition i've come across so far, but a native radio would be much better, but all I can find are so fancy.

How do I know if the radio will work with my car and where can I get a cheap one?

Comment: What year/model of Ford are we talking?

Comment: ford focus 2005 (mk1)

Comment: Go to a junk yard / scrap yard. They have lots of radios - some extracted from cars, some still in them. Spend an afternoon looking for a decent one, then go to Walmart and spend the equivalent of $30 on a basic new deck. Wish I could afford a 2005 car with only 20,000km (12,500miles) on it!

Comment: is 20 000km a typo? if not it might be worth it to fix it, this car will last alot longer than 20k km

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: From what I've read, the '05 Focus did have a CD changer option, which means [this module](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00N9WKTUM) or something similar should plug directly into the back of your stereo. You'll have to find a desirable path to route it out from behind the dashboard, but that's a matter of personal preference. If you don't have a dedicated AUX button, You may have to program the radio to cycle to that option with the press of the CD or RADIO button.

In my experience, [AUX tape deck adapters](https://www.amazon.com/MP3-Cassette-Player-Adapters/b?ie=UTF8&node=13981611) have much better sound quality than the radio transmitters unless you also buy a signal booster, making tape deck adapters a cheaper option as well.

If any of the sister models of your car happened to come with a CD changer, your stock radio probably has the same plug on the back. You'll have to search for your specific model but [this is an example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JHTAPCS) of the type of plug you may be able to find.

If all else fails, you can take the car to a car audio specialist (I've had good experiences with 'Car Toys' in the states, but am in no way affiliated with them). I'd tell them you're not interested in spending much money, and ask them if they have any old decks laying around, or any other cheap options before you throw in the towel and go the tape/radio adapter route.

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, i'm in the sweetspot with a cd-player but no aux. :/ Looking into what I might be able to plugin to the back... trying to figure out what connectors I have...